# failed to get database default returning NoSuchObjectException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

When I start spark I get this warnings:

```
Using Scala version 2.10.5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_77)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
Spark context available as sc.
16/04/03 15:07:31 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
16/04/03 15:07:31 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
16/04/03 15:07:39 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
16/04/03 15:07:39 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
SQL context available as sqlContext.

scala>
```

And also when I execute this command: `var sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)`

I get again this warning:

```
scala> var sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
16/04/03 15:04:31 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
16/04/03 15:04:31 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
16/04/03 15:04:35 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext = org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext@13453610
```

So my question is if you know why this warning is happening and if, although the warning is happening, the command `var sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)` its working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BoneCP is a Java JDBC connection pool and it's tries to bind to a JDBC connection and this is why you receive these warnings. You may suppress this kind of warnings by configure the logger level.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And the other warning about failed to get database default? Do you know if although the warning is appearing the command works correctly?

Comment: Why is it returning a NoSuchObjectException! and Failure?

Answer (score 1):

I meet this warning,too as :

> "Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException"

but i can connect to hive correctly,so check your `hive-site.xml` and i am not sure if this warning will affect the sentry.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have assigned *SQLContext*:

```
sqlContext = pyspark.SQLContext(sc)
```